# Trying to match variables in a PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, string, variables

I'm stuck with a php array problem. I've to a webpage that takes values from a URL, and I need to cross reference those values against some values on the page and if they match output a 'yes'. It's an expression engine bodge job.

The URL is something like domain.com/page/C12&C14

The C12 and C14 represent different categories. I've taken the last bit of the url, removed the 'C' from the values and then exploded the 12&14 into an array.

I print_r the array on the page and it shows: Array ( [0] => 12 [1] => 14 )

So, the values are in the array. Lovely.

Now on the page I have an html list which looks like

10
12
14
15

I want to output a YES next to the variables that are current in the array so the ideal output would be:

10
12 - YES
14 - YES
15

I was trying this but it keeps just saying No next to all of them.

```
$currentnumber = 12;
foreach ($tharray as $element) { 
if ($element == $currentnumber) { echo "Yes"; } else { echo "No"; }  
}
```

I thought that should work, but it's not. I checked and the array and the variable are both stings. I did a strlen() on both to see if they are the same, but $currentnumber outputs '13' and the array variable outputs '2'.

Any ideas as to why it's saying 13?

Is the variable the wrong type of string - and if so how would I convert it?

Comment: what is var_dump($tharray) ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
$tharray = array(10,12,14,15);
$allowed = array(12,14);

echo "<pre>";
foreach ( $tharray as $element ) {
    if (in_array($element, $allowed)) {
        echo $element, " -  Yes ", PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo $element , PHP_EOL ;
    }
}
```

If you don't mind a one line solution

```
array_walk($tharray, function($item)use($allowed) { echo in_array($item, $allowed) ?  $item. " -  Yes ". PHP_EOL : $item . PHP_EOL  ;});
```

Output

```
10
12 -  Yes 
14 -  Yes 
15
```

Comment: Thanks very much Baba - turns out it was an annoying php parsing problem with ExpressionEngine - not a problem with the php code. Thanks for the help